# javascript "return false" does not work

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to control that even user fill the form correctly. So, I add the javascript control in my submit button into click event. In my form, there are many asp.net control and I also have a security code. So, I write a web method working smooth. But, if user fill the security code field wrongly, my "return false" code does not work ant more and page posts back. Here is my javascript codes:

```
function checkFacebookRegister() {
            var error = "";
            var username = $('#<%=tbUsername.ClientID%>').val();

                pattern = new RegExp(/^[0-9a-zA-Z-_]*$/);
                if (username.length >= 4 && pattern.test(username)) {

                    jQuery.ajax({
                        method: 'GET',
                        url: 'ajax/checkUsername.aspx',
                        data: "username=" + username
                    }).done(function (data) {
                        if (data != "true") {
                            error = "Seçtiğiniz kullanıcı adı uygun değil.";
                            $('#errorDivision').show(1);
                            $('#error').html(error);
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    error = "Seçtiğiniz kullanıcı adı minimum 4 karakter olmalı, Türkçe karakter bulunmayan ve noktalama işaretlerinden sadece alt tire içerecek şekilde olmalıdır.";
                    $('#errorDivision').show(1);
                    $('#error').html(error);
                    return false;
                }

                var faculty = $('#<%=ddlFaculty.ClientID%>').val();
                if (faculty == "0") {
                    error = "Şehir, Üniversite ve Fakülte bilgileri eksiksiz girilmelidir.";
                    $('#errorDivision').show(1);
                    $('#error').html(error);
                    return false;
                }

                var password = $('#<%=tbPassword.ClientID%>').val();
                var passwordConf = $('#<%=tbPasswordConf.ClientID%>').val();
                if (password.length < 6) {
                    error = "Seçtiğiniz parola en az 6 karakter olmalıdır.";
                    $('#errorDivision').show(1);
                    $('#error').html(error);
                    return false;
                    } else if (password != passwordConf) {
                        error = "Parolanız tekrarıyla uyuşmamaktadır.";
                        $('#errorDivision').show(1);
                        $('#error').html(error);
                        return false;
                    }

            var securityCode = $('#<%=tbSecurityCode.ClientID%>').val();
            **PageMethods.checkSecurityCode(securityCode, checkSecurityCallBackSuccess, checkSecurityCallBackFailed);**

            if (!$('#<%=cbUserAgreement.ClientID%>').is(':checked')) {
                error = "Üyelik Sözleşmesi' ni onaylamanız gerekmektedir.";
                $('#errorDivision').show(1);
                $('#error').html(error);
                return false;
            }
        }

        function checkSecurityCallBackSuccess(response)
        {
            if (response == false)
            {
                error = "Güvenlik kodubu yanlış girdiniz.";
                $('#errorDivision').show(1);
                $('#error').html(error);
                return false;
            }
        }

        function checkSecurityCallBackFailed(error) {            
            alert(error);
            error = "Belirlenemeyen bir hata oluştu.";
            $('#errorDivision').show(1);
            $('#error').html(error);
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: AJAX is **asynchronous** which means that the `done` callback will happen *after* `checkFacebookRegister` has completed.

Comment: there is no proble with AJAX. After this line, I call the PageMethods which is named **checkSecurityCode**. In this line, the problem is occured

Comment: The problem is that, page method named **checkSecurityCode** return _CallBackFailed_, but refurn false does not work

Comment: [Please create a *reduced test case*](http://css-tricks.com/reduced-test-cases/). People aren't interested in digging through a lot of poorly formatted code.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to move `return false;` outside of your AJAX call, or perhaps refactor the code so that you have one `return false` for the whole function instead of sprinkling them throughout.